# Trying to embed Leaflet's map with Materialize framework

Tags: html, css, leaflet, material-design, materialize

I'm trying to use [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) and within that, I'm trying to embed a [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map.

To my constant chagrin, the photo from the `parallax-container` seems to disappear almost every time I try to add a leaflet map.

This does *not* happen every single time. But it happens often enough on my local desktop that I'm quite befuddled why it happens because every time I take leaflet map out, it works. But when I put it back, the photo works briefly before disappearing.

I tried to no avail to figure out what's causing the disappearance of the photo on the `parallax-container`.

If you have any ideas, I would appreciate feedback on it.

I've uploaded it to [Github's gh-pages](http://arubyist.github.io/testingtestingtesting/). Here's the [Github's repository itself](https://github.com/arubyist/testingtestingtesting).

Yeah, I know the photo is displayed on the link above. Believe me this does not happen on my desktop and there's virtually no difference between that file and the one on my desktop.

Help would be seriously appreciated.

If it helps, here's the [parallex's section](http://materializecss.com/parallax.html) from Materialize framework

Comment: Is this for a mobile site or app with leafletjs bundled in? Where does the material framework come in? Can you provide specific code where problem seems to happen, even if inconsistently?

Comment: @Anthony, I was trying to provide background which framework I was using in case it affected the answer. As for the specific code, believe me, if I knew, I would state that. As it is, all I can see, it's within a specific section which is why I talked about the photo in `parallax-container`, but beyond that, I couldn't figure out why it wasn't showing up on my FF.

Comment: Okay, so it's not really any issue with Material design framework, but with the Materialize toolkit which is meant to emulate/implement the Material design framework. Basically, your issue, as I'm reading it, is that you are implementing one js library (leaflet) within another (materialize) and for whatever reason (issue with your code/browser/the two libraries, whatever) the end result is that when you add a map, an image wrapped in the parralax container breaks. No clue where to start, but knowing what the actual pieces are should help someone help you.

Comment: @Anthony, hm ... um ... that's not how I would have described it, but, ok, I'll take it. Thank you for trying to clarify my problem. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am sure that there is no problem with the code itself, as I have just tested it on the latest dev build of Chrome and Firefox, and there was no problem viewing the image. Are you certain that it is not a problem with the browser on your local computer? Have you tried resetting it?

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I just looked at the local file in both FF and Chrome, and weirdly it works in Chrome, but not in FF (at least right now). Oy vey.

Comment: @seanleven, huh! I just hit refresh in my FF, and the photo appears. Upon hitting refresh again, the photo disappears! This is why it's driving me mad because I don't know if this is safe to use in production.